# 'Swap' arrows in math mode

Tags: math-mode, arrows

How do you get these arrows in math mode? Is there a standard command or package?

[image]

Comment: `$\rightleftharpoons$`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to look up a symbol or identify a letter from a math alphabet or other character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-letter-from-a-math-alphabet-or-other-chara)

Comment: Thanks. I had completely forgotten that existed...